# How fix Spark aggregation max `contains invalid character(s) among ` error?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The simple aggregation leads to invalid characters error:

```
val result = df
  .groupBy($"id".alias("g_id"), $"my_date".alias("g_my_date_int")).max("my_date_int")
result.write.mode(saveMode = SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("file://...")
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name "max(my_date_int)" contains
invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;
```

The special point here that `max` method do not have any alias parameters. So how to group over 2 columns and select `max`
 over int field?

Comment: Can you share the schema of dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

The error:

```
Attribute name "max(my_date_int)" contains
invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;
```

means you can't `write` a `Dataframe` with invalid column names, in your cases because it contains parenthesis.
Try renaming the max column, e.g.,

```
val result = df
  .groupBy($"id".alias("g_id"), $"my_date".alias("g_my_date_int")).agg(max("my_date_int") as "max_my_date_int")
result.write.mode(saveMode = SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("file://...")
```

Comment: Using an alias worked form me - -> agg(max("my_date_int").alias("max_my_date_int")

Answer (score 0):

At times, direct max cannot work, try enclosing max in "agg" as below

```
df.groupBy($"id".alias("g_id"), $"my_date".alias("g_my_date_int")).agg(max("my_date_int"))
```